# ListBox does not stay within Window borders when put into a Grid with rows having MinHeight

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, grid

I have a `Grid` with two rows sized in 1:3 proportion; the first row has `MinHeight` set to a non-zero value. When I put a `ListBox` into the second row, its size is not limited by the window borders:

[image: Screenshot]

The problem occurs if `MinHeight` is applied (that is, if the window is small). If I replace the problematic `ListBox` with a `Button`, the problem disappears (buttons always stay within window borders).

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfGridLayoutMinMax.MainWindow" x:Name="self"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="300" Width="300" MinHeight="200" MinWidth="200">
    <Control.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items, ElementName=self}"/>
        </Style>
    </Control.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" MinHeight="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="0"/>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace WpfGridLayoutMinMax
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public List<int> Items { get; set; }

        public MainWindow ()
        {
            Items = Enumerable.Range(0, 20).ToList();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**: What causes this problem? How to make `ListBox` stay within window content area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the buggy `Grid`. Its `MeasureOverride` returns a bigger size than the constraint, even though there's no reason for this.

I've implemented `ForceCellSizes` attached property which fixes the issue.

```
public static class GridProps
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CalculateCellSizesProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "CalculateCellSizes", typeof(bool), typeof(GridProps),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, (o, a) => CalculateCellSizes_OnChanged((Grid)o, a)));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ForceCellSizesProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ForceCellSizes", typeof(bool), typeof(GridProps),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, (o, a) => ForceCellSizes_OnChanged((Grid)o, a)));
    private static readonly DependencyProperty DummyGridProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "DummyGrid", typeof(Grid), typeof(GridProps),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey RowActualHeightPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly(
        "RowActualHeight", typeof(double), typeof(GridProps),
        new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowActualHeightProperty = RowActualHeightPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ColumnActualWidthPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly(
        "ColumnActualWidth", typeof(double), typeof(GridProps),
        new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnActualWidthProperty = ColumnActualWidthPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    public static bool GetCalculateCellSizes (Grid grid)
    {
        return (bool)grid.GetValue(CalculateCellSizesProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCalculateCellSizes (Grid grid, bool value)
    {
        grid.SetValue(CalculateCellSizesProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetForceCellSizes (Grid grid)
    {
        return (bool)grid.GetValue(ForceCellSizesProperty);
    }

    public static void SetForceCellSizes (Grid grid, bool value)
    {
        grid.SetValue(ForceCellSizesProperty, value);
    }

    private static Grid GetDummyGrid (Grid grid)
    {
        return (Grid)grid.GetValue(DummyGridProperty);
    }

    private static void SetDummyGrid (Grid grid, Grid value)
    {
        grid.SetValue(DummyGridProperty, value);
    }

    public static double GetRowActualHeight (RowDefinition row)
    {
        return (double)row.GetValue(RowActualHeightProperty);
    }

    private static void SetRowActualHeight (RowDefinition row, double value)
    {
        row.SetValue(RowActualHeightPropertyKey, value);
    }

    public static double GetColumnActualWidth (ColumnDefinition column)
    {
        return (double)column.GetValue(ColumnActualWidthProperty);
    }

    private static void SetColumnActualWidth (ColumnDefinition column, double value)
    {
        column.SetValue(ColumnActualWidthPropertyKey, value);
    }

    private static void CalculateCellSizes_OnChanged (Grid grid, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if ((bool)args.NewValue)
            grid.SizeChanged += Grid_OnSizeChanged;
        else
            grid.SizeChanged -= Grid_OnSizeChanged;
    }

    private static void Grid_OnSizeChanged (object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var grid = (Grid)sender;
        foreach (RowDefinition row in grid.RowDefinitions)
            SetRowActualHeight(row, row.ActualHeight);
        foreach (ColumnDefinition column in grid.ColumnDefinitions)
            SetColumnActualWidth(column, column.ActualWidth);
    }

    private static void ForceCellSizes_OnChanged (Grid grid, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if ((bool)args.NewValue) {
            Action initDummyGrid = () => {
                Grid parentGrid = (Grid)grid.Parent, dummyGrid = CreateDummyGrid(grid);
                parentGrid.Children.Add(dummyGrid);
                SetDummyGrid(grid, dummyGrid);
            };
            if (grid.IsLoaded)
                initDummyGrid();
            else
                grid.Loaded += (o, e) => initDummyGrid();
        }
        else {
            Grid parentGrid = (Grid)grid.Parent, dummyGrid = DestroyDummyGrid(grid);
            parentGrid.Children.Remove(dummyGrid);
            SetDummyGrid(grid, null);
        }
    }

    private static Grid CreateDummyGrid (Grid grid)
    {
        var dummyGrid = new Grid { Visibility = Visibility.Hidden };
        SetCalculateCellSizes(dummyGrid, true);
        foreach (RowDefinition row in grid.RowDefinitions) {
            var dummyRow = new RowDefinition { Height = row.Height, MinHeight = row.MinHeight, MaxHeight = row.MaxHeight };
            dummyGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(dummyRow);
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(row, RowDefinition.HeightProperty,
                new Binding { Source = dummyRow, Path = new PropertyPath(RowActualHeightProperty) });
        }
        foreach (ColumnDefinition column in grid.ColumnDefinitions) {
            var dummyColumn = new ColumnDefinition { Width = column.Width, MinWidth = column.MinWidth, MaxWidth = column.MaxWidth };
            dummyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(dummyColumn);
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(column, ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty,
                new Binding { Source = dummyColumn, Path = new PropertyPath(ColumnActualWidthProperty) });
        }
        return dummyGrid;
    }

    private static Grid DestroyDummyGrid (Grid grid)
    {
        Grid dummyGrid = GetDummyGrid(grid);
        SetCalculateCellSizes(dummyGrid, false);
        foreach (RowDefinition row in grid.RowDefinitions)
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(row, RowDefinition.HeightProperty);
        foreach (ColumnDefinition column in grid.ColumnDefinitions)
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(column, ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty);
        return dummyGrid;
    }
}
```

**Attached properties**

The following attached properties are defined in the `GridProps` class:

1. **`Grid.CalculateCellSizes`** *(read/write)* — adds bindable `RowActualHeight` and `ColumnActualWidth` properties to `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` of the grid, respectively.
2. **`Grid.ForceCellSizes`** *(read/write)* — fixes the problem described in the question.
3. **`RowDefinition.RowActualHeight`** *(read-only)* — bindable `RowDefinition.ActualHeight` property. Set `CalculateCellSizes` on the owner grid to `true`.
4. **`ColumnDefinition.ColumnActualWidth`** *(read-only)* — bindable `ColumnDefinition.ActualWidth` property. Set `CalculateCellSizes` on the owner grid to `true`.

**How to use**

1. Wrap problematic `Grid` in an empty `Grid`.
2. Set `GridProps.ForceCellSizes` to `true`. Example from the question becomes:

   ```xml
   <Grid>
       <Grid local:GridProps.ForceCellSizes="True">
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="1*" MinHeight="100"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <ListBox Grid.Row="0"/>
           <ListBox Grid.Row="1"/>
       </Grid>
   </Grid>
   ```

**How it works**

It adds an empty dummy grid with the same rows and columns as in the original grid, then binds heights and widths of the original grid to actual heights and widths of the dummy grid.

Essentially, the example above becomes:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding RowDefinitions[0].(local:GridProps.RowActualHeight), ElementName=dummyGrid}" MinHeight="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding RowDefinitions[1].(local:GridProps.RowActualHeight), ElementName=dummyGrid}"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="0"/>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="dummyGrid" Visibility="Hidden" local:GridProps.CalculateCellSizes="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" MinHeight="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem appears every time the content is too large (for Button too if you set height larger than remaining space).

Don't know if you like my solution but I've added an additional Grid for measuring the remaining space. Unfortunatly it is not possible to get ActualHeight from second RowDefinition directly (it has no usable value). That's why I've added one more control (the Dummy). Now you can limit `ListBox.MaxHeight` to Dummy.ActualHeight and it stays within window.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="Dummy" Grid.Row="1" />

    <Grid Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" MinHeight="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="0" />
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" MaxHeight="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Dummy}" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I've been experimenting a little. The origin of the problem seems to lie in the `ScrollViewer` class as a large button within a scroll viewer causes the problem too. / `RowDefinition.ActualHeight` does have a value, but the property isn't bindable, unfortunately. / Your code works, but the added complexity of XAML isn't a good thing... I'll try to come up with some attached property trickery.

Comment: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19120388/293099 With my attached properties, only a minor change to XAML is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you set two rows with 1* and 3*, and say that 1* is minimally 100(px) high, then the second row wil minimally be 300(px). Makes sense right? So if you want to keep this ratio, and want to keep the min height for the first row you could set the minheight of you window to 400(or a little bit more).

Comment: I need the second row to fill the remaining space when the window height is less than 400; and take 3/4 of space if the window height is more than 400. Your solution is too simplified. Like I said in the question, the behavior I want is supported by WPF (it works with buttons), so simplifying is definitely not the way to go. Also, if you run my example, you'll notice that your calculations are incorrect (the height of the listbox is not fixed to 300 when the window is small). And `Height=Auto` is plain wrong, because it will make the first listbox occupy all space if there're many items.

Comment: you are right, i was to quick with my answer. It was just to give you an idea of why your logic might be wrong. Now it is more clear what your trying to accomplish though...